# How to use flatmap to store snapshot data into a variable

Tags: swift, database, snapshot

Using the debugger, it shows that snapshot has 3 values but posts has 0 so I think I'm incorrectly using flatMap. Perhaps there is a better way to store the data into posts.

```
static func observePosts(for user: User = User.current, withCompletion completion: @escaping (DatabaseReference, [Post]) -> Void) -> DatabaseHandle {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.username)

    return ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
            return completion(ref, [])
    }
        let posts = snapshot.flatMap(Post.init)
        completion(ref, posts)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think snapshot is just a picture of the data available at that time. You cannot directly match the snapshot objects to Post type. Please do as follows

```
let posts = snapshot.flatMap({(post) -> Post in

                let value = post.value as? Dictionary<String, String>

                let id = value?["id"] ?? ""
                let author = value?["author"] ?? ""
                let title = value?["title"] ?? ""
                let body = value?["body"] ?? ""

                return Post(id: id, author: author, title: title, body: body)
            })
```

Comment: I have "let snapshot = snapshot.children" if that is what you mean.